# Using two tablets simultaneously as a dual-screen

Tags: nexus-7, remote-access

I have had a Nexus 7 (2012 version) for quite some time now. Recently I saw an offer for a really cheap refurbished Nexus 7. Since I've been really happy with my tablet, I decided to order an additional one.

Not really having a plan in mind, I'm now looking for cool projects to use my second Nexus 7 for. So my question:

- Are there possibilities to use both tablets simultaneously in a dual screen setup, sort of like extending one screen onto the other, for some real multitasking? I know I can just open a browser on one, and edit text on the second, but then there is no interaction between them, like sharing the clipboard or dragging files to one another.
  I have been searching, but all I could find was extending screens between some PC OS and a tablet/phone, but not between tablets themselves.